# MonadReader without functional dependency

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

Is there a version of `MonadReader` in a library somewhere that doesn't have the functional dependency from `m -> r`?

If I have a function that requires reader contexts `A`, `B` and `C`, and I want to call a function that requires reader contexts `A` and `C`, it seems to be that I have bundle all my contexts up into a structure like `(A, B, C)`, split them and recombine them in `(A, C)` to pass into another function.

This seems to go against how constraints generally compose.

Like if I have a functions:

```
f :: (C1 a, C2 a) => a -> a
g :: (C2 a, C3 a) => a -> a
```

Then

```
h :: (C1 a, C2 a, C3 a) => a -> a
h = g . f
```

Is perfectly fine.

But if I try:

```
f :: (MonadReader C1 m, MonadReader C2 m) => m a -> m a
g :: (MonadReader C2 m, MonadReader C3 m) => m a -> m a
```

Then

```
h :: (MonadReader C1 m, MonadReader C2 m, MonadReader C3 m) => m a -> m a
h = g . f
```

this is going to spit the dummy, because of that pesky functional dependency.

I understand that without the functional dependency, `ask` may require type annotations, but this is a reasonable compromise in my case, particularly when simply using the output of `ask` elsewhere determines it's type.

Is there a version of `MonadReader` without this functional dependency? Or do I need to roll my own? Or is there some other approach than just manually pulling apart/putting together tuples (in which case I feel I might as well just pass the context explicitly as the first argument).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's [lensy stuff for this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.2/docs/Control-Lens-Zoom.html) via the `Magnify` type class.

> ```
> magnify :: ((b -> k c b) -> a -> k c a) -> m c -> n c
> ```
>
> Run a monadic action in a larger environment than it was defined in, using a Getter. [For example,]
>
> ```
> magnify :: Monoid w => Getter s t -> RWST s w st c -> RWST t w st c
> ```

I've also developed [effect-stack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/effect-stack) as a sort of proof-of-concept alternative approach, though as far as I know there are currently exactly zero users -- not even me.

> If a transformer stack includes two transformers that provide the given effect, mtl does not provide a clean way to disambiguate which one is wanted; the topmost one is always chosen.
>
> This package provides tools for disambiguating without being forced to choose a particular transformer stack.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, [mtl-unleashed](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-unleashed-0.6.1/docs/Control-Monad-Readers.html) fits exactly the bill here.