# What is the pattern to combine 2 MonadState instances into the same monad?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, state-monad

Say that I'm implementing a TicTacToe game server. In order to better test it I define a class for the effect of getting a move from a player:

```hs
class (Monad m, MonadState TTTState m) => TTTMonad m where 
  getMove :: m Move
```

In "production" the `getMove` will be an IO action waiting for input from the user, but when testing this I want to provide a list of pre canned `Move`s to replay a particular game.

So my initial approach was to create a tuple with the moves to be replayed and the TTTState itself:

```hs
newtype ReplayMonad a = ReplayMonad { unReplay :: State ([Move], TTTState) a }
```

but then I cannot have `MonadState [Move]` and `MonadState TTTState` for the same monad instance because of the functional dependency. I want this double dependency because I wanted to do:

```hs
instance TTTMonad ReplayMonad where
  -- Consume the first move in the list and provide it as a result of the context
  getMove = do 
    m:ms <- gets fst
    modify (\(_, gs) -> (ms, gs)) -- Have a new state with the remaining moves
    return m
```

All my code is only parameterized by `MonadState TTTState` and I just wanted to introduce the extra piece of state because I need to retrive `Move`s from within the context of the monad.

What am I doing wrong? What is the usual pattern to deal with this kind of extensions to a simpler monad?

Comment: `TTTState` vs `GameState`? Should they be the same?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I will edit

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved without breaking the fundep `m->s` in the class definition `class Monad m => MonadState s m | m -> s `. Maybe a solution could involve using some lenses or other "optics" but I'm not very familiar with those.

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate?): https://stackoverflow.com/q/76658232/791604

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `MonadState` instances. You only need `MonadState TTTState` since it is a superclass of `TTTMonad`, but instead of `MonadState ([Move], TTTState)` you can either have specialized variants of `get` and `put` for `ReplayMonad`

```
getMoves :: ReplayMonad [Move]
putMoves :: [Move] -> ReplayMonad ()
```

or use the `ReplayMonad` constructor, since the underlying monad exactly gives you access to the whole state.

```
   getMove :: ReplayMonad [Move]
   getMove = ReplayMonad $ do
     (m : ms, gs) <- get
     put (ms, gs)
     return m
```